# Unity TextMesh Pro

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, думаю многие знают плагин для Unity TextMesh Pro. Я узнал как добавлять спрайты по их индексам. Но вопрос в том, как бы их анимировать?) У меня к каждому спрайты доп. спрайты, по 4 штуки. Негде не нашел как анимировать спрайты прямо в TextMesh Pro

Comment: TMP для текста, какие спрайты хотите там анимировать?

Comment: Значит вы только его так и использовали. У него миллион возможностей, включая и гипер ссылки и другое. Да и глупо подключать большие плагины (либы) для использования только одной функции. Я уже сам понял как анимировать все что нужно)

Comment: Тогда, было бы хорошо, если бы Вы самостоятельно ответили на свой вопрос, и помогли бы другим разработчикам которые могли бы столкнуться с данной проблемой